No cron event is being executed on my WordPress
I have a problem on my Wordpress, no cron event is being executed on my WordPress. Checking in the WP_Control plugin, I see that no hooks are being executed. What could be the problem? I have tried to run them manually but without success. By the way, in wp-config.php, I have enabled: define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', false); Does anyone have an idea where to look?
Thanks.

WordPress cron is not what a lot of people think it is. If your host supports it, hands down I would recommend using your system's cron to activate WordPress's. You can do it the older/harder way, but I'd recommend using the official WP CLI, it is much easier. If these aren't options, turn on WP_DEBUG and check the logs, something might be silently failing.

There may be several reasons why your cronjob is not executed on the WP side. Here are some of them, shamelessly stolen from the WP Crontrol FAQ:

Low traffic websites may not trigger the event runner often enough
A fatal error caused by a plugin or theme may break the event runner
A plugin or theme may intentionally or unintentionally break the event runner
BasicAuth, a firewall, password protection, or other access restrictions may block the event runner
A problem with your web hosting or web server may break the event runner
Long-running events may temporarily block the event runner
High traffic websites may suffer from sequential processing issues that block the event runner
An alternative cron runner is in place but is not working as expected or has stalled

In my experience, it is a good idea to first activate the WP debug and search for fatal errors in the log.

WordPress cronjobs are not executed as ‘real’ crons by default, but are triggered by page views. The cron job is only executed when a visitor uses the system, whether in the front or back end.
With a hosting provider (or on your server), you can have the WordPress cronjob queue processed via real cronjobs. This involves setting the DISABLE_WP_CRON flag you mentioned earlier.
